# sleep2 works not properly in apue?

Tags: c, linux, signals

The code in apue of sleep2 is as follows:

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static jmp_buf env_alrm;

static void sig_alrm(int signo)
{
    longjmp(env_alrm, 1);
}

unsigned int sleep2(unsigned int nsecs)
{
    if(signal(SIGALRM, sig_alrm) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        return (nsecs);
    }

    if(setjmp(env_alrm) == 0)
    {
        alarm(nsecs);
        pause();
    }

    return (alarm(0));
}

int main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        sleep2(1);
        printf("test\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the code is just one string "test" and then hangs

According to my understanding, the sleep2 functions works as follows:

1. jmp_buf env_alrm is set to 0
2. when the program call sleep2 at the first time, the `alarm(nsecs)` will be called
3. at the time of nsecs, the `sig_alrm` will be called and `longjpm` set the env_alrm struct to be 1
4. then it jumps to `if(setjmp(env_alrm) == 0)`, while it's not true, so it runs the statement `return alarm(0)`

at the second time when sleep2 was called, the value of struct jmp_buf env_alrm is 1, so the `alrm(nsecs)` would not be called, and in my opinion that's what makes the funciton work not properly, so I change the code as follows:

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static jmp_buf env_alrm;

static void sig_alrm(int signo)
{
    longjmp(env_alrm, 1);
}

unsigned int sleep2(unsigned int nsecs)
{
    if(signal(SIGALRM, sig_alrm) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        return (nsecs);
    }

    alarm(nsecs);
    if(setjmp(env_alrm) == 0)
    {
        pause();
    }

    return (alarm(0));
}

int main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        sleep2(1);
        printf("test\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, the second program produces the same output as the first program does, So my question is:

What makes the two programs print only one "test" and then hangs?

Answer (score 0):

Your codes are doing just the same thing as ones on book. Whenever signal handler longjmp() to the sleep2() the alarm() was never(and shall never) executed again. And for your problem I recommend you continue reading the book until section on sig_setjmp() functions. 
Since I have no idea about your system, I think the hang up is most probably due to the longjmp() that doesn't restore the signal masks. That means first time you entered signal handler and system automatically masks this signal to avoid reentrance. And when handler returns this masked signal(SIGALRM in your case) is unmasked(restored). POSIX doesn't define whether longjmp() shall restore this signal. So you may have masked SIGALRM in the handler and doesn't unmask it. Consequently the program gets stuck on the second loop. 
To verify this, you may use pr_mask() function in the sig_alrm() handler. It's a function written by the author to print the mask of current process. Keep me notified about the result.